# setting the text color of UIBarButtonItem by appearance proxy

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uikit

Here's what is being set and it's close to the color I need:

```
NSDictionary *barButtonItemTitleAttributesEnabled = @{
                                               NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont MRFontLightOfSize:17],
                                               NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]
                                               };
NSDictionary *barButtonItemTitleAttributesDisabled = @{
                                                      NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont MRFontLightOfSize:17],
                                                      NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.25f]
                                                      };

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:barButtonItemTitleAttributesEnabled forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:barButtonItemTitleAttributesDisabled forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

But I'd prefer to somehow set the disabled text color to the same color as the selected state, is there a way to do that with the appearance proxy calls?

Also tried this:

```
NSDictionary *barButtonItemDisabled = [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] titleTextAttributesForState:UIControlStateSelected];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:barButtonItemTitleAttributesEnabled forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:barButtonItemDisabled forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Comment: Is your issue here that you want to get the text color the system sets when you push down on the button? So if your button is red when you push down it makes it a little bit different red? Just want to make sure I understand before proving answer

Comment: If you want the same color then pass in the same color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

resolved by removing TextTitleAttribute code above and setting the toolBar tintColor appearance proxy:

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

this made it so that just enabling or disabling the buttons set them to the right color.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give different colours for different items then you should use

```
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                   target:self action:@selector(done)];

[doneButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor whiteColor],  NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Otherwise you should just simply write

```
[toolBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```